# Does "overflow: scroll" cause scroll bars to appear even when not necessary?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I created a text box over an image for a client that has a overflow set to scroll so that the text does not spill over when the page is resized. For some reason I do not see scroll bars on my screen but my client sees them on both the x and y axis.

[image: scrollbar issue appears on x and y axis]

Does anyone know if having "overflow: scroll;" causes scroll bars to show up  in certain versions of Chrome and if there is a solution to make them invisible?

My client's alternative would be to use images with text on them and I would like avoid that for myriad reasons including accessibility.

I have an offline version of this as well and still see no scrollbars.

I am using a Mac and they are using PC but, to my knowledge and recollection, this shouldn't make a difference for this issue.

You can [view the page here](http://www.ralock.com/markets/).

The page is cramped at the moment as we are doing a stylesheet overhaul that is offline.

Here is a snippet of the CSS I am using for this. Thinking some of it may be redundant. Not sure if removing any parts of this will change things visually as I can't replicate the issue.

```
 .boxwrapper {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 10px 15px; 
}

.imagebox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px; 
  height: 85%; 
  width: 35%; 
 overflow: scroll;

}

.imagebox p{ 
color: #000; 
 overflow: scroll;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

Expected results are for the page to render with no scroll bars like it does for me. 
[image: my results with the code above - no scrollbars]

Comment: Most probably you are looking for `overflow: auto`, which shows scrollbars only when necessary.

Comment: Why are you adding the overflow property to all the paragraphs in the first place?

Comment: Ohhh I will try this and see if they can see it that way as well. I want to say auto wasn't working for me properly but I'll give it a go. I still don't know why they can see scroll bars and I can't.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß overflow is there so that when the boxes are resized, specifically for mobile, the text stays inside the box no matter how much text is added.

Comment: But you'd want that on the boxes only, not on each paragraph, surley? So it would be enough to add `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;` to your boxes only (classes `.imagebox` and `.imageboxleft`)

Comment: @ConstantinGroß correct, I kinda swept past the paragraph part of the question - my bad.